# H10 error, desc="App crashed" showing "Application Error" on the heroku page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am trying to deploy my application from my desktop to heroku. But shoiwng application error on the page. Here is the display of heroku logs :

```
2015-05-17T14:23:16.824327+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-05-17T14:23:16.796436+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2015-05-17T14:23:16.796435+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
2015-05-17T14:23:17.773437+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-05-17T14:23:17.760552+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-05-17T14:23:57.689913+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=pacific-beach-3105.herokuapp.com request_id=85de2fe6-d894-4f53-a995-1285be93c58d fwd="203.110.246.22" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-05-17T14:23:59.999420+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=pacific-beach-3105.herokuapp.com request_id=7384ee1f-1efc-4801-9a4a-a34a0d17f8fb fwd="203.110.246.22" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-05-17T14:24:01.833524+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=pacific-beach-3105.herokuapp.com request_id=934a68f4-84e5-4259-9455-52d8f8602c06 fwd="203.110.246.22" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-05-17T14:24:31.083965+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by sameerrrana@gmail.com
2015-05-17T14:24:34.043331+00:00 heroku[run.6109]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2015-05-17T14:24:34.759590+00:00 heroku[run.6109]: State changed from starting to up
2015-05-17T14:24:38.220213+00:00 app[run.6109]:   ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
2015-05-17T14:24:38.954062+00:00 heroku[run.6109]: State changed from up to complete
2015-05-17T14:24:38.944714+00:00 heroku[run.6109]: Process exited with status 0
2015-05-17T14:25:11.918187+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=pacific-beach-3105.herokuapp.com request_id=d5969403-490c-4da1-aa01-905bfd39b9a1 fwd="203.110.246.22" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-05-17T14:34:31.213525+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `rails console` by sameerrrana@gmail.com
2015-05-17T14:34:35.566430+00:00 heroku[run.6202]: Awaiting client
2015-05-17T14:34:35.900197+00:00 heroku[run.6202]: State changed from starting to up
2015-05-17T14:35:05.572297+00:00 heroku[run.6202]: Error R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to attach to process
2015-05-17T14:35:07.029088+00:00 heroku[run.6202]: Process exited with status 128
2015-05-17T14:35:07.045904+00:00 heroku[run.6202]: State changed from up to complete
2015-05-17T14:40:45.980758+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by sameerrrana@gmail.com
2015-05-17T14:40:50.488405+00:00 heroku[run.7608]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2015-05-17T14:40:51.155554+00:00 heroku[run.7608]: State changed from starting to up
2015-05-17T14:40:56.358175+00:00 app[run.7608]:   ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
2015-05-17T14:40:57.410610+00:00 heroku[run.7608]: State changed from up to complete
2015-05-17T14:40:57.396701+00:00 heroku[run.7608]: Process exited with status 0
2015-05-17T14:41:11.499509+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=pacific-beach-3105.herokuapp.com request_id=ddc2f1be-2fb0-43d6-a24d-00e9a6631be0 fwd="203.110.246.22" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I have been to every question regarding Application error and Error H10 but can't solve it . Please help

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in the `Gemfile`.

```
gem 'pg', group: :production
```

then

```
bundle install
```

and commit the changes to the github. And then run the command

```
git push heroku master
```

Comment: I have already included 'pg' gem with 'rails_12factor' gem too, with group production. still not working